# How can I create a straight "beveled" corner (or two) with an outline using CSS?

Tags: css, border, outline

Similar to [these](http://scottpdawson.com/development/three-methods-for-creating-beveled-corners-css-css3-or-jquery/), but with a separate border. I asked this question earlier, but didn't realize there were other methods besides using linear gradients.

Examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5rZE.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not pure CSS (and probably not exactly what you're looking for), but you could just do a larger element first that just forms the border, and then have a smaller sibling element with offset afterwards:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="foreground"></div>
```

and then the css:

```
#background{
  position: absolute;
}
#foreground{
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

(Obviously, you would have to add all of the styling and extra tags for the beveling.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. This might gave you an idea of how to create it with css.

[Beveled border with css](http://jsfiddle.net/drjorgepolanco/o18vqwgg/)

HTML

```
<div class='box'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img class='cart' src="http://www.rotweinelang.at/themes/wein/img/elements/smallShoppingCartIcon.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 40px 40px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}

.cart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -4px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```